# How to solve "Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'" when deploy django + mysqlclient in railway.app

Tags: mysql, django, railway

I'm trying to deploy my Django website on the railway.app host. It works out smoothly without the "MySQL" database. It works smoothly with "MySQL" at localhost too, but when I upload it to railway it fails. I wonder if there are some unfinished dependencies. How does i fix this? My database code looks like this:`DATABASES = {

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQLHOST'),
    'PORT': os.environ.get('MYSQLPORT'),
    'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQLDATABASE'),
    'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQLUSER'),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQLPASSWORD'),
    
}
```

}`

I'm programming on a windows desktop.